# URL error in Yeoman angular generator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem after generating angular with yeoman generator. After run project I find my URL like this: **localhost:9000/#!/**, Why in my URL there is character '!'?

How can I remove the **'!'** character from my URL, Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got resolved with following code.You can write in your app.js file

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

and go through the link:

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1380

Comment: You can upvote it and tick for that because some one can use it as a correct answer @andrewMK